# X11: is there any way to extract window structure from some window?

Tags: python, x11

In X11, is there any way to extract window structure from some window?
For example, I want to read programmatically some label from window with some id.
In my case target program is written in Qt.

Comment: Windows are basically just bunches of pixels. So probably not.